# django charField accepting only numbers

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have this django charField and I want it to accept only numbers. How can we achieve this in django?

```py
class Xyz(models.Model):
    total_employees = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want total_employees to accept only numbers and not strings from my client. I want to put a check on api end too.

Comment: Why don't you use an [IntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.IntegerField)?

Comment: no we can have really large numbers too .

Comment: When saving, you can validate that every character in `total_employees` is a digit. But you should really consider using integerfield

Comment: lol unless that's just an example field name, that company has to employ the third of the world's population for IntegerField to be not good enough

Answer (score 4):

You could make it into a IntegerField or BigIntegerField at form level you make a form for the model.

```
class Xyzform(ModelForm):
     total_employees =forms.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model=Xyz
        fields=['total_employees ']
```

or you may add a validation at form level:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
 # paste in your models.py
 def only_int(value): 
    if value.isdigit()==False:
        raise ValidationError('ID contains characters')

class Xyzform(ModelForm):
     total_employees =forms.CharField(validators=[only_int])
    class Meta:
        model=Xyz
        fields=['total_employees ']
```

Answer (score 3):

There is [BigIntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#bigintegerfield) which you could use instead.

If not and you REALLY MUST use a CharField you could use [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/). Create a validator which tries to convert the field to int, wrapped in a try except block. In the except you raise a `ValidationError` if its not int.

Answer (score 2):

**total_employees** should need **only positive numbers**.

[**PositiveBigIntegerField**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#positivebigintegerfield) allows values **from 0 to 9223372036854775807**:

```py
total_employees = models.PositiveBigIntegerField()
```

[**PositiveIntegerField**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield) allows values **from 0 to 2147483647**:

```py
total_employees = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

[**PositiveSmallIntegerField**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#positivesmallintegerfield) allows values **from 0 to 32767**:

```py
total_employees = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

In addition, there are no **"NegativeIntegerField"**, **"NegativeBigIntegerField"** and **"NegativeSmallIntegerField"** in **Django**.